# Start Activity is slow and the new activity is empty

Tags: android, performance

This is my first android app, I'm transitioning from iOS development.
I'm trying to change to a different activity. However, it takes multiple seconds (about 3) for my new empty activity to appear.

Here is my code to send to transition to the new activity:

```
public void openStats(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StatsActivity.class));
}
```

Here is my onCreate of my new activity:

```
public class StatsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stats_page);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why this is taking so long? I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S5 also.

This is the log when opening the new activity:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.NAME.reflexmath time:53311650
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources:/data/app/APPNAME2/base.apk / 1.0 running in APPNAME rsrc of package null
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a1db7f7 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@58ff7f6 time:53313401
```

And `stats_page.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:baselineAligned="false" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"> 

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.1"></LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.8"> 

<ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/reflexmath5" 
android:id="@+id/imageView10" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:cropToPadding="false" 
android:adjustViewBounds="false" 
android:scaleType="fitCenter" /> 
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.1"></LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.7" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" 
android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
android:weightSum="1" 
android:id="@+id/progView"> 

<ImageView 
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/hbmlogo" 
android:id="@+id/imageView11" 
android:elevation="1dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.3" 
android:scaleType="fitCenter" /> 

<ProgressBar 
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/xpBar" 
android:scaleY="5" 
android:progress="50" 
android:layout_weight="0.7" 
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="-13dp" /> 
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.25"> 

<TextView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:gravity="center" 
android:text="HIGH SCORE 3456" 
android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" 
android:textSize="1sp" 
android:id="@+id/highScoreLbl" /> 
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1" > 

<ImageButton 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/play" 
android:id="@+id/imageButton9" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent" /> 

<ImageButton 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/stats" 
android:id="@+id/imageButton10" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
android:onClick="openStats" /> 
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.1"></LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.4"> 

<ImageButton 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/audioon" 
android:id="@+id/imageButton12" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
android:scaleType="fitCenter" /> 

<ImageButton 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/adson" 
android:id="@+id/imageButton13" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
android:scaleType="fitCenter" /> 
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.1"></LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What if you remove the `setRequestedOrientation()` call? Does it still take a long time to load the new activity?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes it still takes the same amount time. It also takes the same amount of time to return to the original activity by pressing the back button on my Samsung.

Comment: Is your device connected to your development machine via USB? What happens if you disconnect and run your app?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes it is connected via USB, I tried disconnecting and reconnecting. Still feels like exactly 3 seconds every time, to and from my new activity.

Comment: @james check the developer options on the device, you might have actually changed the animation speed to be 5X slower :-)

Comment: disconnect and run your app. Don't reconnect.

Comment: @Blundell Which options specifically do you think can cause this behavior?

Comment: I'm not 100% it is just this option but: Settings > Developer Options > Transition Animation Scale  (mine is set to 1x which is the norm)

Comment: I disabled animations, Still takes the same amount of time. All other apps are behaving normally. Also tried running disconnected, Still slow. I also tried on an emulator, It's slightly faster to open the new activity but still as slow to return.

Comment: I added the log of the activity opening

Comment: is there anything complicated going on in the MainActivity? or any custom views inside `stats_page`?

Comment: @Blundell The new activity is empty, And I commented all code out of the main. Still the same delay.

Comment: it's not empty you load an XML file `setContentView(R.layout.stats_page);` what is in that file? If its just default .. then its your device :)

Comment: @Blundell I've added the new activity code to the question.

Comment: I've tried on another newer phone, Still got a noticeable delay.

Comment: like I said, what is in `stats_page.xml`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131935/discussion-between-blundell-and-james).

Comment: As a side note, there are better ways to add padding than a bunch of empty LinearLayouts.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I was trying to make every layout, including the blank layouts proportional. This does the job, but what do you recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "proporitonal". Unfortunately these comments are not the best place to go into further discussion about a new topic unrelated to your original question. You will probably need to learn more about what is available in the the Android API to find the best solution to meet your needs. I suspect there are other ways to get the look you want that will also help improve efficient loading of the UI elements beyond the image bottle neck you discovered here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using big images and allowing the system to scale them will be memory intensive and therefore slow on some/most devices.

You should provide the correct size images for the screen size available, this way the least scaling is needed.

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix slow image loading from resource, I use a custom view that uses Glide image loading library to show the images.

```
public class GlideImageView
        extends ImageView {
    public GlideImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, -1);
    }

    public GlideImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public GlideImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public GlideImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    int drawableResource = 0;

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        TypedArray a = null;
        if(defStyle != -1) {
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.GlideImageView, defStyle, 0);
        } else {
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.GlideImageView);
        }
        drawableResource = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        a.recycle();

        ViewUtils.waitForMeasure(this, new ViewUtils.OnMeasuredCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMeasured(View view, int width, int height) {
                if(!isInEditMode()) {
                    if(drawableResource != 0) {
                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(drawableResource).dontAnimate().into(GlideImageView.this);
                    }
                } else {
                    setImageResource(drawableResource);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
public final class ViewUtils {
    public interface OnMeasuredCallback {
        void onMeasured(View view, int width, int height);
    }

    public static void waitForMeasure(final View view, final OnMeasuredCallback callback) {
        int width = view.getWidth();
        int height = view.getHeight();

        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            callback.onMeasured(view, width, height);
            return;
        }

        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override public boolean onPreDraw() {
                final ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
                if (observer.isAlive()) {
                    observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }

                callback.onMeasured(view, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private ViewUtils() {
    }
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="GlideImageView">
        <attr name="image_resource" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And then can be used as

```
        <the.package.GlideImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                app:image_resource="@drawable/image"/>
```

Using the dependency

```
compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that was making the app slow was an 1200x1200 image that was being scaled down to a size of roughly 200x200. When I removed this, the entire app worked fast again. Is this a common occurrence? Can android not handle down scaling very well? Anyway, Thanks for the help!